# Will orbot work for instagram?

Tags: anonymity, orbot

I just tried to log on to Instagram on my PC via Tor, and I could not type my username and password. The same problem exists on Covert Browser (Tor browser for iPhone). Is it possible to use Instagram via Orbot?

Comment: The purpose of using tor is to acheive a higher level of anonymity than what you normally experience online... Instagram collect and sell user data with the sole intention of generating profit.. You shouldn't be using any form of social media if you intend to go unnoticed.

Answer (score 1):

Instagram works very well with Orbot on android, I personally use it daily with 'transparent proxying' enabled on my phone.